# What type of connector is this 3-pin socket marked "DC24V" on a printer?

Tags: identification, socket

[image: Photo of meta panel showing the power socket]

The device in question is a printer, I've never seen such a connector before...

Comment: google `epson receipt printer power supply connector` and look at the pictures

Answer (score 5):

It's a fairly unique hole pattern, and the only connector I found at a cursory glance that matches is the [Kycon KPJX-3S](http://www.kycon.com/2013Catalogpage/DC%20Power/KPJX.pdf):

[image]

It is a 48VDC-rated power jack, and the applications listed in the datasheet seem in-line with the comment you made about it being on a printer.